# Does SMTPLIB support retry other IPs in mail server if the first one fail?

Tags: python

I'm working with smtplib of python and I have a question.

For example: `mail_server = smtp.gmail.com`

And it has:

> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> smtp.gmail.com  canonical name = gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
>
> Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
>
> Address: 173.194.202.109
>
> Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
>
> Address: 173.194.202.108
>
> Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
>
> Address: 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::6d

And I define smtp:

```
fro = 'example@gmail.com'
to = 'rcpt_example@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText("something"))
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)
smtp.sendmail(fro, to, msg.as_string())
smtp.close()
```

Does `smtplib` support retry with other IPs (of mail server) if the first one fails?

And how can we get the current IP which is using to send email?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a library, not an MTA.

Comment: Hi @KlausD., I'm not really clear about how smtplib work with mail_server, can you tell me more?

Comment: It renders the mail data, connect to *one* server, authenticates, sends your mail. If anything fails it will raise an exception. Everything else is your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/smtplib.py), there is no retry logic; it simply tries to open a socket, and if that fails, it fails.

When it succeeds, `self.socket` contains the raw socket object, so you can query that for things like `.getpeername()`.

You can take a (slightly) closer look at what it does by setting a debug level, though that alone does not reveal which IP address it selects out of the possible ones.

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> s = smtplib.SMTP()
>>> s.set_debuglevel(2)
>>> s.connect('smtp.gmail.com')
10:34:20.953509 connect: ('smtp.gmail.com', 25)
10:34:20.954076 connect: to ('smtp.gmail.com', 25) None
... much time passes ...
^C
```

(Just to be explicit, port 25 is not supported by Gmail; that's why it times out ... eventually.)

Here is a working handshake where we call `getpeername()` to see the remote IP address:

```
>>> s.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
10:54:50.226282 connect: ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
10:54:50.227435 connect: to ('smtp.gmail.com', 587) None
10:54:50.356376 reply: b'220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp\r\n'
10:54:50.356493 reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp'
10:54:50.356511 connect: b'smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp'
(220, b'smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp')
>>> s.sock.getpeername()
('2a00:1450:4010:c08::6c', 587, 0, 0)
>>> s.quit()
10:55:15.630288 send: 'quit\r\n'
10:55:15.663442 reply: b'221 2.0.0 closing connection c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp\r\n'
10:55:15.663511 reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'2.0.0 closing connection c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp'
(221, b'2.0.0 closing connection c30sm365713lfj.0 - gsmtp')
```

I could find no explicit documentation for the `debuglevel` but it looks like `1` enables debugging and `2` adds timestamps in front of the debug messages.

A proper implementation should query the MX records in priority order.

```
bash$ host -t mx gmail.com
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```